# reStructuredText: backquote text immediate followed by other letters

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am using Sphinx with reStructuredText. I can use backquotes to create an inline literal, say

```
This is an ``object``
```

=> This is an `object`.

However, if there is an letter immediately follows the inline literal, the back-quoted text is not rendered as inline literal

```
They are ``object``s.
```

=> They are ``object``s.

How can I get the following desired rendering?

=> They are `object`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, you need to escape the `s`, e.g.

```
They are ``object``\s.
```

Result will be

They are `object`s.

You can try it in this [online RST editor](http://rst.ninjs.org/?n=a8f21df46891e09b93816849ab68c31c&theme=nature)